# Google Earth crashing when opening

Tags: crash, google

Is there a definitive way to stop Google Earth from crashing when it loads?
I'm on OS X 10.9.2 using Google Earth 7.1.2.2041
I've tried reinstalling, I've looked on [various forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23774161#23774161) about removing Internet plugins from the Library folder - nothing seems to work.

Crash report fragment:

```
Process:         Google Earth [45962]
Path:            /Applications/Google Earth.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Earth
Identifier:      com.Google.GoogleEarthPlus
Version:         7.1 (7.1.2.2041)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [226]
Responsible:     Google Earth [45962]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2015-02-12 22:29:58.022 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  8B4E424F-12C4-8F81-629F-2A2B48AC0FDF

Sleep/Wake UUID: 78DD0C85-CC8D-4A19-8BDC-3E9D7348E86E

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000018f7dc44

VM Regions Near 0x18f7dc44:
    __BSS                  0000000018f72000-0000000018f79000 [   28K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/NPLoaderOSX.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NPLoaderOSX
--> __RODATA               0000000018f79000-0000000019030000 [  732K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/NPLoaderOSX.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NPLoaderOSX
    __RSRC                 0000000019030000-0000000019034000 [   16K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/NPLoaderOSX.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NPLoaderOSX

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                             0x18f7dc44 0 + 418896964
1   NPLoaderOSX                     0x18e0fb8c @DbgEvalFrame + 1648
2   NPLoaderOSX                     0x18e0fe4a @DbgEvalFrame + 2350
3   dyld                            0x8fe2745b ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 283
4   dyld                            0x8fe275c4 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 64
5   dyld                            0x8fe2392c ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 294
6   dyld                            0x8fe237bc ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 62
7   dyld                            0x8fe18cff dyld::runInitializers(ImageLoader*) + 88
8   dyld                            0x8fe2025a dlopen + 566
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x91b11b75 dlopen + 70
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9210b0e9 _CFBundleDlfcnLoadFramework + 185
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9208c232 _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 850
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9210b321 CFBundleLoadExecutable + 33
13  QtWebKit                        0x03659c28 qWebKitVersion() + 4088
14  QtWebKit                        0x03659fcd qWebKitVersion() + 5021
15  QtWebKit                        0x03507b3b 0x2dfb000 + 7392059
16  QtWebKit                        0x0350345e 0x2dfb000 + 7373918
17  QtWebKit                        0x0350372b 0x2dfb000 + 7374635
18  QtWebKit                        0x0361df44 0x2dfb000 + 8531780
19  QtWebKit                        0x034a876a 0x2dfb000 + 7001962
20  QtWebKit                        0x0349693a 0x2dfb000 + 6928698
21  QtWebKit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by looking at the log.

I removed

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/NPLoaderOSX.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NPLoaderOSX
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem the Facebook plugin fbplugin_1_0_0.plugin.  Once it was deleted, Google Earth opened normally.

Comment: Tried everything and eventually deleted "fbplugin_1_0_1.plugin" from Internet Plug-ins folder, and now works.

Comment: Yep, Facebook plugin for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem on iMAC running 10.9.5. I didn't have either of those previously mentioned plugins. I did have only one, a "Dish Anywhere Player.plugin" in Users/(My Name)/Library/Internet Plug-ins.   When I trashed that plug-in then Google Earth would open and operate properly.

Answer (score 1):

My guilty plugin was:

WebVideoPlugin.plugin

Installed by Swann videos systems

I moved my plug-ins to a different folder ½ at a time until GE stayed open.

Comment: God bless you all! Thanks to your advice I compared the Internet plugins folder of back up and present settings. The WebVideoPlugin.plugin was actually present even in the past when Google earth worked, but an Sp7WebVideoPlugin.plugin had been added when and how I ignore. I deleted the Sp7WebVideoPlugin.plugin and Google Earth works again properly.